# Node separate the lines in data separated by a semi-colon

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, string

I have some data that looks like the one below and the end of each line is separated by a semi-colon.

```
id=0345 f1() status=1;
id=7645 f2() status=3;
```

How can I get each line into an array (without the ending semi-colon).

I've tried this:

```
var arr = data.split(';');
console.log(arr);
```

But it didn't work.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could remove all the `;` at the end of each line and then `split` at `\n`

```js
const str = `id=0345 f1() status=1;
id=7645 f2() status=3;`

const arr = str.replace(/;$/gm, '').split(/\n/g)

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just split on a semicolon and newline:

```js
 

const str = `id=0345 f1() status=1;
id=7645 f2() status=3;`
const arr = str.split(";\n");
console.log(arr);
```